# squid ssl bump sslv3 enforce to allow old sites

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid

I have configured squid(3.4.2) as ssl bumped proxy. I am setting proxy in firefox(29) to use squid for https/http.
Now it works for most sites, but some sites which support old SSL proto(sslv3) break, and I see squid not employing any workarounds for those like browsers do.

Sites which should work: https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com/  , https://www.mahaconnect.in , https://kz.grfc.ru/portal/faces/app/materials/active.jspx

As a workaround I have set sslproxy_version=3 , which enforces SSLv3 and above sites work.

My question: is there a better way to do this which does not involve enforcing SSLv3 for servers supporting TLS1 or better.

Now I know openssl doesn't automatically handle that. But I imagined squid would.

My squid conf snipper:

> http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/usr/local/squid/certs/SquidCA.pem
>
> always_direct allow all
>   ssl_bump server-first all
>   sslcrtd_program /usr/local/squid/libexec/ssl_crtd -s /usr/local/squid/var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
>
> client_persistent_connections on
>   server_persistent_connections on
>
> sslproxy_version 3
>
> sslproxy_options ALL
>
> cache_dir aufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid 100 16 256
>
> coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid
>
> strip_query_terms off
>
> httpd_suppress_version_string on
>
> via off
>
> forwarded_for transparent
>
> vary_ignore_expire on
>
> refresh_pattern ^ftp:     1440    20% 10080
>   refresh_pattern ^gopher:  1440    0%  1440
>   refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0   0%  0
>   refresh_pattern .     0   20% 4320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was more in sync with Serverfault than stackoverflow. I got it answered there.
https://serverfault.com/questions/604824/squid-ssl-bump-sslv3-enforce-to-allow-old-sites

I have kept the question subject same in both sites and leaving this question be, in case somebody stumbles upon this question here instead of serverfault. Moderators are free to chuck this question out of stackoverflow.

I had to stop supporting all the ciphers openssl supports and put my custom list which would be extended as and how required. 
https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com/ supports RC4-MD5 so my cipher list is:

sslproxy_cipher EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH